# How do I get reputation for writing docs?

Tags: discussion, reputation, documentation, documentation-editor

When I write big part of documentation in one commit, is there any method, how Stack overflow distinguish it from small changes, when it's giving reputation for that?

Comment: I created an entirely new topic with a very good example and I only got +2 https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-core/2869/localization#t=201607230936525590911 srsly what the hell...